# "Orphan Symbol" problem with QGIS marker line symbol

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, markers, floating

I'm experiencing a problem with the way QGIS Essen 2.14.12 draws a marker line symbol at the end of a polyline.  It only occurs sometimes, and sometimes moving (even slightly) the mapping within the window will make the "orphan" symbol disappear, or make it reappear.  Zooming in/out will also have the same seemingly random effect.  I hope the attached image shows the problem - note the floating V at the top end of the brown line.

[image: orphan v marker symbol at line end]

The offending V is an inverted V symbol and offset by 8mm relative to the non-offset symbol (which plays nice and behaves itself) see settings below.

[image: settings for line with orphan symbol]

Despite searching, I've not found an answer to this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue arises because the symbol is asked to be located 8 mm away from its supposed location.

To overcome this, you will want not to offset the symbol but rather the marker location along - but on - its line. You will need a style with 1 line and 2 marker lines, one of which having an `offset along the line` of 8mm. This ensures it will not go outside of the line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent - resolves the problem perfectly.  Thank you.